# Need efficient algorithm in combinatorics

Tags: algorithm, cryptography

I am trying to find the best (realistic) algorithm for solving a cryptography challenge, in which:

- the given cipher text C is made of about 6000 characters taken in the set S={A,B,C,...,Y,a,b,c,...y}. So |S| = 50.
- the encryption scheme does not allow to have two identical adjacent characters in C
- 25 letters in S are called Nulls, and are unknown
- these Nulls must be removed from C to obtain the actual cipher text C' which can then be attacked.
- the list of Nulls in C is named N and |N| is close to |C|/2 = 3000
- so: |N| + |C'| = |C|

My aim is to identify the 25 Nulls, satisfying these two conditions:

- there may not be two identical adjacent characters in C'
- there may not be two identical adjacent Nulls in N

Obviously by brute force there are 50!/(25! 25!) = 126410606437752 combinations of 25 Nulls in S, so this is not a realistic approach.

I have tried to recursively explore the tree of sets of Nulls and 'cut branches' as much and as soon as possible. 
For example, when adding a letter of S to the subset of Nulls, if the sequence "x n1n2 x" appears in C where x is not yet a Null and n1n2 are Nulls, then x should be a Null too.
However this is not enough for a run-time lower than a few centuries...

Can you think of a more clever algorithm for identifying these 25 Nulls ?

Note: there might be more than one set of Nulls satisfying the two conditions

Comment: You can upgrade the cutting algorithm - if `nxn` is in the cipher text, then x and n are in the same group - null or not-null. this way you can group quite a few chars together. improving on this - if `y[nx]+y` is in the string, so y is in the same group as n and x.

Comment: also notice that there is no actual difference between N and C' - you can't distinguish between them.

Comment: can you please give the link of the challenge if its public?

Comment: @Shashwat Kumar: you can find it and many others at: https://www.mysterytwisterc3.org/en/challenges/level-iii/handycipher-part-4

Comment: @elyashiv: nxn => n and x in the same group. If so, ynxy in the same group too, OK with you.

Comment: Strings C and C' are both given and we are searching for the string N satisfying both conditions, am I right?

Comment: @piotrekg2: no, both C' and N are unknown

Comment: I think you should clarify the problem statement. In particular define what the input and output is and how to obtain output from the input.

Comment: @piotrekg2: the input is C. The unknown is the subset of 25 letters of S called Nulls. They separate C into 2 strings: N = containing the letters of C which are Nulls , and C' containing the letters of C which are not Nulls.
In both N and C' there may not be adjacent identical letters.

Comment: So the solution would be as follows: take any set L of 25 letters not from C'. Construct N as a concatenation of letters from L, for example if  L = { a, b, c, ..., z} then N = abc...zabc...z and so on until you reach the length of 3000. Your C is a concatenation of N and C', if the last letter of N is equal to the first letter of C' then swap the last two letters of N. I'm not sure how it helps in decrypting the ciphertext, but the constructed N and C satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

lets try something like this:

- Create a list of sets - each set contains one char from S. the set is the null chars.
- while you have more then two sets:

  - for each set

    - search the cipher text for `X[<set-chars>]+X`
    - if found, union the set with the set X in it.
  - if no sets where united, start recursing with two sets united.

You can speed up things if you keep a different cipher text for each set, removing from it the chars in the set. if you do so, the search is easier - you are searching for XX, witch is constant length. every time you union two sets you need to remove all the chars in the sets from the cipher text.

The time this well take depends on the string C you are given.

An explanation about the sets - each set is an option for C' or N. If you find that A and X are in the same group, then {A, X} is either a subset of N or of C'. If later you will find the same about Y and B, then {Y, B} is a subset. Later, finding a substring YAXAXY means that Y is in the same group as A and X, and so will B, because it's with Y. At the end you will end with two groups - one for C' and one for N, witch you can't distinguish between.

Comment: to alyashiv: thank you for your time.
I don't fully understand your method. We start with 50 sets, each containing a char of S, fine. Why "while you have more than two sets" ? All I need is a set of 25 chars. What would the final 2 sets contain ?
Also the loop "for each set" is unclear to me, as when merging 2 sets, one of the sets disappears, right ?
Example: at the first iteration, when considering the set 1 containing 'A', if one find XAX in the ciphertext, then set {A} and set {X} are merged, so we have set 1 = {A,X} and set 24 has been removed.
What am I missing ?

Comment: @user863967 1. you carry on until you have two sets because you will end up with two - one is C' the other is N. 2. right. when you merge two sets one disappears. That doesn't really matters - so you won't check set 24, just check any other set with 1, witch contains 24.

Comment: Got it. I have implemented phase1 (all possible unions) and end up with 26 sets: 17 with 1 letter, 4 with 2 letters, 3 with 3 letters, 1 with 5 letters and 1 with 11 letters. Can you be more specific on the recursive process to be used then ?

Comment: @user863967 basically guess, like the most naive way to do it - for each two sets, try to merge them and carry on, just like you wanted to do at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

elyashiv's method is the good one.

It is very fast.

I have produced the two sets C' and N, which are equivalent.
The sub-sets of S, S1 and S2 which produce C' and N are adequately such that S = S1 U S2.

Thank you.